# webapi end point is reached, but all parameters are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following end point :

```
    [HttpGet("/{auditReviewId}/{actioneeId?}/{entries?}")]
    public IEnumerable<AuditReviewActionDto> GetAuditReviewActions(int auditReviewId, int? actioneeId = null, int? entries = null)
```

and I call it the following way using HttpClient

```
var client = LocalHttpClient.CreateClient("UarBase");

var response = client.GetAsync("api/AuditDashboard/GetAuditReviewActions?auditReviewId=" + logId + "&actioneeId=" + SelectedKey + "&entries=" + Limit).Result;
```

It doesn't matter what I set LogId, SelectedKey or Limit to, when I hit the endpoint they are always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the HttpGet with `[HttpGet("/{auditReviewId}/{actioneeId?}/{entries?}")]`, you're specifying your inputs as **route** parameters, but then you're passing them as **query** parameters.

If you'd like to pass the parameters via the query, remove them from your route (just use `[HttpGet]` or just supply the base route), and then tag each of your method inputs with a `[FromQuery]` attribute to designate they come from query parameters.